# Using JSON as property value in Apache Camel

Tags: json, apache-camel, properties-file

The following code line works fine

```
.setBody(constant("{\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"type\":{\"value\":\"channels\"}},\"should\":{},\"must_not\":{\"missing\":{\"field\":\"sourceId\",\"existence\":true,\"null_value\":true}}}},\"fields\":[\"sourceId\",\"callSign\",\"name\"],\"from\":0,\"size\":10000}"))
```

However when the JSON value is specified in a properties file as shown below, it fails if called as follows:

```
.setBody(simple("{{es.stations}}"))
```

es.stations is set as shown below

```
es.stations={"filter"\:{"bool"\:{"must"\:{"type"\:{"value"\:"channels"}},"should"\:{},"must_not"\:{"missing"\:{"field"\:"sourceId","existence"\:true,"null_value"\:true}}}},"fields"\:["sourceId","callSign","name"],"from"\:0,"size"\:10000}
```

The exception thrown is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing {{ from the text: {"filter":{"bool":{"must":{"type":{"value":"channels"}},"should":{},"must_not":{"missing":{"field":"sourceId","existence":true,"null_value":true}}}},"fields":["sourceId","callSign","name"],"from":0,"size":10000}
```

Is it possible to store JSON in properties files and if so what escape characters if any should be used

Comment: Why dont you prefer using object and classes and parsing it to String jason usin GSON? By using that you can store your object anywhere you want.

Comment: You need to quote the }} as its assume its part of a nested {{ }} placeholder. So try \}\}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Claus. However I still get the same error despite many attempts with using \ character to escape } and also { occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `simple` expression. you can use `constant` as per your example. That would work fine. Provided that you are using `spring-boot` binding.

```
.setBody(constant("{{es.stations}}"))
```